# Error Unsupported Grant Type

Tags: vba, excel, api, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to connect to an API, using MS Excel VBA. The parameters needed for login are grant type, username, and password.

I have came up with the code below, however i am getting the error :

> {"error":"unsupported_grant_type"}

Can anyone enlighten me where i am doing it wrongly?

```
Sub test()

Dim objHttp As Object
Dim json As String
Dim user, password As String

user = "user1"
password = "password1"
json = "{""grant_type"":""password"",""username"":""" & user & """,""password"":""" & password & """}"

MsgBox json

Dim result As String

Set objHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
url = "http://dummywebsite.com"
objHttp.Open "POST", url, False

objHttp.SetRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/json"
objHttp.Send (json)
result = objHttp.ResponseText

MsgBox result

End Sub
```

The code is actually working, and it is due to user rights after testing with another user account.

Comment: Do you define "grant_type" ?

Comment: you mean in my code or backend? i have directly input the grant type into my code.

Comment: I just saw user and password defined but no grant_type, sorry if I misunderstood.

Comment: the grand_type is password, and i placed it in the code. apparently the code is working, i borrowed another user account to try. Will approach the administrator regarding user rights. Thank you though @Solar Mike

Answer (score 0):

Try:

Headers:
- Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
- Accept-Charset: UTF-8
- Authorization: [Your Authorization Code]

Body:
username=[username]&password=[password]&grant_type=password